# Never ending messages with RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

We are using MassTransit(3.5.2) together with RabbitMQ(3.6.6). We are having a problem with a message that never gets removed from the queue (even if we have read and consumed the message).
To read from the queue we have implemented an IConsumer class.

The only thing we are doing is closing the sender (abrupt). 
After that the message never gets acknowledged and rabbitmq is continuing to send the same message to our consumer all the time.

Have anyone else got the same problem and how did you solve this issue?

:: Update from comments ::

We had already checked the log files and it says: "closing AMQP connection <0.18285.1> ([::1]:57008 -> [::1]:5672): client unexpectedly closed TCP connection ". 
That doesnt feel that wierd since i am actually closing the tcp connection unexpectedly with killing the .exe file :)

Regarding the log files from masstransit we have also done that and we do not get any error, we only gets two debug messages. 
One that we have received and one that we are sending the result. 
DEBUG 47 MassTransit.Messages - RECEIVE rabbitmq://localhost/[VirtualHost]/[ConsumerName] N/A ContractCommand CommandConsumer(00:00:00.0364932) 
DEBUG 30 MassTransit.Messages - SEND rabbitmq://localhost/[VirtualHost]/bus-[ComputerName]-[Sende‌​rName].Server.vshost‌​-4bayyydsf9rfs3qzbdk‌​gx8bbr1?durable=fals‌​e&autodelete=true d0700000-762f-c85b-f03a-08d4679c39d4 Result

One observation that I have made in my consumer is that at the same time as I am force closing my sender I get an MessageNotConfirmedException followed by some AlreadyClosedException from RabbitMQ. 
And it's after that we get in the infinite loop when MT does not set the ACK/NACK. (and in the infinite loop I do not get any MessagenNotConfirmedException). 
Also for my consumer to properly work again I need to restart my consumer then it will be ACK/NACKed.

MessageNotConfirmedMessage: "'MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.MessageNotConfirmedException‌​' in mscorlib.dll Additional information: rabbitmq://localhost/[VirtualHost]/bus-[ComputerName]-[Servi‌​ce].Server.vshost-4b‌​ayyydsf9rfsf3ybdkgxg‌​5h8b => The message was not confirmed by RabbitMQ
'RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.AlreadyClosedException' Additional information: Already closed: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=404, text="NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'bus-[ComputerName]-[ServiceName].Server.vshost-4bayyydsf9rf‌​s3qzbdkgx8bbr1' in vhost '[VirtualHost]'", classId=60, methodId=40, cause=

Comment: Which version of MT?

Comment: Consumer code would help. Not sure what is (abrupt)

Comment: I have updated the versions in the question now (3.5.2 for MT and 3.6.6 for RabbitMQ).

Regarding Consumer code it does just perform an validation and then returning. 

If I wasnt clear it's the SENDER that I close abrupt(just killing the .exe) and it's the consumer that gets the same message again and again after I have closed the sender.

If I would close the sender in a controlled fashion (when not sending messages) I do not get any problem. So it's ONLY when killing the process at the same time as I am sending messages.

Comment: You should add a logging library to your consumer service, and set the logging level to debug, and see what comes out of it. Because there will be an error logged someplace explaining the issue. I'm guessing it can't create the _error queue to move the bad message. Also check the RabbitMQ broker log file for invalid/inconsistent exchanges and/or bindings.

Comment: Thanks for your input Chris,

We had already checked the log files and it says: "closing AMQP connection <0.18285.1> ([::1]:57008 -> [::1]:5672):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
".
That doesnt feel that wierd since i am actually closing the tcp connection unexpectedly with killing the .exe file :)

Comment: Regarding the log files from masstransit we have also done that and we do not get any error, we only gets two debug messages. One that we have received and one that we are sending the result. 
DEBUG 47 MassTransit.Messages - RECEIVE rabbitmq://localhost/[VirtualHost]/[ConsumerName] N/A ContractCommand CommandConsumer<ContractCommand>(00:00:00.0364932)
DEBUG 30 MassTransit.Messages - SEND rabbitmq://localhost/[VirtualHost]/bus-[ComputerName]-[SenderName].Server.vshost-4bayyydsf9rfs3qzbdkgx8bbr1?durable=false&autodelete=true d0700000-762f-c85b-f03a-08d4679c39d4 Result

Comment: One observation that I have made in my consumer is that at the same time as I am force closing my sender I get an MessageNotConfirmedException followed by some AlreadyClosedException from RabbitMQ. 
And it's after that we get in the infinite loop when MT does not set the ACK/NACK. (and in the infinite loop I do not get any MessagenNotConfirmedException).
Also for my consumer to properly work again I need to restart my consumer then it will be ACK/NACKed.

Comment: MessageNotConfirmedMessage:
"'MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.MessageNotConfirmedException' in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: rabbitmq://localhost/[VirtualHost]/bus-[ComputerName]-[Service].Server.vshost-4bayyydsf9rfsf3ybdkgxg5h8b => The message was not confirmed by RabbitMQ"

Comment: 'RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.AlreadyClosedException'
Additional information: Already closed: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=404, text="NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'bus-[ComputerName]-[ServiceName].Server.vshost-4bayyydsf9rfs3qzbdkgx8bbr1' in vhost '[VirtualHost]'", classId=60, methodId=40, cause=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated our code to use MassTransit 3.5.7 and after that I have not been able to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you are done processing your queue object, you can mark it as successful by  `BasicAck(e.DeliveryTag, false)`

Comment: Thats what MT should be doing in the background. So it doesn't feel like an acceptable solution to hack in on my own.